# How to get column details (column, datatype) of table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-structure

[image]

I am new to databases, I just created a table using "New Table", but I want to list of columns and their properties as shown in the screenshot.

What is the SQL command for this? I googled it before coming here but it's of no use, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: Or use the `sys` objects. You'll want to `tables`, `columns` and `types` objects.

Comment: Post code as code rather than images to avoid downvotes. Another method is `EXEC sp_help N'dbo.UIDemo_Input;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Information\_Schema Syntax for finding servername, table and column details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042279/sql-information-schema-syntax-for-finding-servername-table-and-column-details)

Comment: @wibeasley: I improved your edit ...

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use This Query:

```
    SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='YourTableName'
```

and this link may be helpful.
visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query

```
SELECT TAB.name AS TableName, COL.name AS ColumnName, TYP.name AS DataTypeName, 
TYP.max_length AS MaxLength
From sys.columns COL
INNER JOIN sys.tables TAB
On COL.object_id = TAB.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types TYP
ON TYP.user_type_id = COL.user_type_id
```